# Apache, Directory directives, and relative paths

Tags: apache-2.2

say for example I have a configuration something like this

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

    DocumentRoot "path/to/docroot"

    <Directory /path/to/docroot/private>
        #blah
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/docroot>
        #blah
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/docroot/anotherdir>
        #blah
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm constantly qualifying paths using /path/to/docroot. I want to be able to declare the
path value of /path/to/docroot at the head of the file just once, and find a way to declare subsequent directory directives relative to that path.

Is there anything like this I can do? (Pretend Var is a madeup directive that lets you declare a path value then refer to it later)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    Var DocRoot "path/to/docroot"
    DocumentRoot DocRoot

    <Directory DocRoot/Private>
      #blah
    </Directory>

    <Directory DocRoot>
      #blah
    </Directory>

    <Directory DocRoot/anotherdir>
      #blah
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything like this I can use? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) is used to set variables that can be passed to CGI and SSI pages.  What you want to do does not necessarily have any native support that I am aware of.

One solution would be to use the third party module called [mod_macro](http://cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/), which would allow a more dynamically generated httpd.conf but is not exactly what you are seeking.

If you have mod_perl installed, you can embed perl code within the httpd.conf using `<perl>` and `</perl>`, which would allow a more dynamic httpd.conf.  mod_perl executes it on startup.  If you are not already running mod_perl, the overhead introduced would not be worthwhile.

A third option would be to dynamically generate your configuration using a set of scripts, which would be outside of Apache all together.  Perl would be a very useful language for this particular application.

Comment: Dammit! I had tried mod_env, but hadn't used the ${} syntax. Knew it had to be simple- thanks Warner :)

Comment: Sorry Warner- that doesn't work. Can you confirm that it works for you? I don\t believe its a configuration issue on myside- I have mod_env module loaded. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry.  Could you revisit and amend your answer?  It fails to expand, e.g., "DocumentRoot ${MyRootDir}/public_html".

Comment: My mistake, please see my revision user48842.

Comment: Your link for mod_env is wrong — it points to mod_macro. Try http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html